# Is any self-referencing function considered 'recursion'?

Tags: javascript, recursion

With respect to JavaScript, I can see two distinct ways of writing self-referencing functions:

***Divide and Conquer-like algorithms such as factorial or merge sort, where values are calculated recursively from ever-decreasing-in-size samples:***

```
const factorialOf20 = (function factorial(n) {
    return (n == 0) ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1);
})(20);
```

***Loops via self-calling functions*** (I find this useful when the loop contains code that is executed asynchronously - for example a network request - but the loop iterations need to be serialized).

```
var result = '';
(function doLoop(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i++;
        request('http://...', function(err, res, body) {
          result += body;
          doLoop(i);
        });
    };
})(0);
```

In JavaScript, when looping via recursion, each function call sets up a new execution context and doesn't seem (to me) any different to a case when different functions are called.

Is this still considered recursion?

Comment: try some big numbers in those bits of code (in the order of 60000) - do you get an error like `InternalError: too much recursion`? well, that's recursion :p

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the difference between 2 approaches...

Comment: *"I can see two distinct ways of writing self-referencing functions"* -- it's the other way around. You identified two programming techniques that can be implemented using recursive functions. The recursive functions can be used for other things too. Their existence is not defined in any way by these programming techniques. And the aforementioned programming techniques can also be implemented without using recursive functions.

Comment: Non-self-referencing functions can still spawn recursive processes; see the classic `even`/`odd` [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) example – Self-referencing functions can also spawn *non*-recursive (iterative) processes; compare your `factorial` to an implementation that uses a [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this still considered recursion?

Ultimately this is more a matter of nomenclature and hence opinion than a purely technical question. However, consider that the likes of:

```
function A(num)
{
    if (num < 3) B(num);
}

function B(num)
{
    A(num - 1);
}
```

Has also long been considered recursion; neither `A` nor `B` call themselves directly, but there is recursion in the chain of calls as a whole. As such both `A` and `B` are recursive since `A` still causes `A` to be called, and likewise `B`.

And as such your example is analogous in that while `doLoop` does not call `doLoop`, it does cause `doLoop` to be called.

Where some people would object to calling this *recursion* is that `doLoop` will not be part of the chain of calls of a previous `doLoop`, or may not (it's possible to write versions where it isn't clear whether `doLoop` is called immediately or not). This more specific definition of *recursion* though is more useful when considering how languages are implemented (e.g. is there a call-stack or another mechanism that allows for recursion) than in how they are used.

Answer (score 3):

I guess in your second example you actually meant something like

```
function doLoop() {
   if (hasAsyncWork)
      doAsyncWork({callback: doLoop})
}
```

so the function schedules itself to be run at some later point rather than calling itself directly. This pattern is used a lot in javascript and has many variations, consider for example:

```
function fun() {
   do something
   setTimeout(fun, 100)
}
```

or

```
function fun() {
  return doAsyncWork().then(fun)
}
```

or even

```
async function fun(jobs) {
  if (jobs.length)
     await fun(jobs.slice(1))
}
```

Technically this is not recursion, at least in the traditional sense.

Comment: That is what I meant (I've changed my question to reflect that). Is there a technical term for this if it's not recursion?

Comment: @ZachSmith: I'm not aware on any accepted term for this use case, but it's so common that it definitely deserves a name, how about "asyncursion"? ;)

Comment: or how about `yncursion` (pronounced incursion)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps contrary to georg, I would argue that both georg's and your async examples are in fact examples of recursion in the traditional sense. Let's look at the definition in Wikipedia for a recurrence relation:

```
...an equation that recursively defines a sequence or 
multidimensional array of values, once one or more
initial terms are given: each further term of the sequence
or array is defined as a function of the preceding terms.
```

What's important to look at is whether the async calls define a sequence of values (think of "value" abstractly), each stemming from a previous term. Whether the generation is delayed or even conditional does not seem relevant to me.

Comment: yes, in the "philosophical" sense, recursion is everything that refers to itself, so we can talk about a recursive process, that forks itself, or a recursive type. In the narrow sense however, I tend to think of recursive functions as something that runs within the same stack (and causes it to overflow ;), and asyncs run on different stacks.